# How do you get rid of the red X in Microsoft PowerPoint preview pane

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Sometimes PowerPoint 2013 adds a red X to the left hand side pane for no apparent reason.

How do you get rid of the red X and get the normal preview pane back

[image: PowerPoint with strange X's on the left]

[image: PowerPoint version]

Comment: Did you Google your issue?..https://www.startpage.com/do/search?query=get+rid+of+the+red+X+in+microsoft+powerpoint+preview+pane&cat=web&pl=chrome&language=english

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of the red X by simply rebooting the computer. There were Office updates waiting for installation thus requiring reboot. After installation PowerPoint opened the file as usual.